# Performance of looping over an Unboxed array in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, monads

First of all, it's  great.  However, I came across a situation where my benchmarks turned up weird results.  I am new to Haskell, and this is first time I've gotten my hands dirty with mutable arrays and Monads.  The code below is based on [this example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Using_ST_Array).

I wrote a generic monadic `for` function that takes numbers and a step function rather than a range (like `forM_` does).  I compared using my generic `for` function (Loop A) against embedding an equivalent recursive function (Loop B).  Having Loop A is noticeably faster than having Loop B.  Weirder, having both Loop A and B together is faster than having Loop B by itself (but slightly slower than Loop A by itself).

Some possible explanations I can think of for the discrepancies.  Note that these are just guesses:

- Something I haven't learned yet about how Haskell extracts results from monadic functions.
- Loop B faults the array in a less cache efficient manner than Loop A.  Why?
- I made a dumb mistake; Loop A and Loop B are actually different.

  - Note that in all 3 cases of having either or both Loop A and Loop B, the program produces the same output.

Here is the code.  I tested it with `ghc -O2 for.hs` using GHC version 6.10.4 .

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.IArray
import Data.Array.MArray
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed

for :: (Num a, Ord a, Monad m) => a -> a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
for start end step f = loop start where
    loop i
        | i <= end   = do
            f i
            loop (step i)
        | otherwise  = return ()

primesToNA :: Int -> UArray Int Bool
primesToNA n = runSTUArray $ do
    a <- newArray (2,n) True :: ST s (STUArray s Int Bool)
    let sr = floor . (sqrt::Double->Double) . fromIntegral $ n+1

    -- Loop A
    for 4 n (+ 2) $ \j -> writeArray a j False

    -- Loop B
    let f i
        | i <= n     = do
            writeArray a i False
            f (i+2)
        | otherwise  = return ()
        in f 4

    forM_ [3,5..sr] $ \i -> do
        si <- readArray a i
        when si $
            forM_ [i*i,i*i+i+i..n] $ \j -> writeArray a j False
    return a

primesTo :: Int -> [Int]
primesTo n = [i | (i,p) <- assocs . primesToNA $ n, p]

main = print $ primesTo 30000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried benchmarking this with [Criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) and GHC 6.12.1, and Loop A looks only slightly faster for me. I definitely don't get the weird "both together are faster than B alone" effect.

Also, if your step function really is just a step and doesn't do anything wacky with its argument, the following version of `for` seems a bit faster, especially for smaller arrays:

```
for' :: (Enum a, Num a, Ord a, Monad m) => a -> a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
for' start end step = forM_ $ enumFromThenTo start (step start) end
```

Here are the results from Criterion, where `loopA'` is your loop A using my `for'`, and where `loopC` is both A and B together:

```
benchmarking loopA...
mean: 2.372893 s, lb 2.370982 s, ub 2.374914 s, ci 0.950
std dev: 10.06753 ms, lb 8.820194 ms, ub 11.66965 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking loopA'...
mean: 2.368167 s, lb 2.354312 s, ub 2.381413 s, ci 0.950
std dev: 69.50334 ms, lb 65.94236 ms, ub 73.17173 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking loopB...
mean: 2.423160 s, lb 2.419131 s, ub 2.427260 s, ci 0.950
std dev: 20.78412 ms, lb 18.06613 ms, ub 24.99021 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking loopC...
mean: 4.308503 s, lb 4.304875 s, ub 4.312110 s, ci 0.950
std dev: 18.48732 ms, lb 16.19325 ms, ub 21.32299 ms, ci 0.950<
```

And here's the code:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unboxed

import Criterion.Main

for :: (Num a, Ord a, Monad m) => a -> a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
for start end step f = loop start where
    loop i
        | i <= end   = do
            f i
            loop (step i)
        | otherwise  = return ()

for' :: (Enum a, Num a, Ord a, Monad m) => a -> a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
for' start end step = forM_ $ enumFromThenTo start (step start) end

loopA  arr n = for  4 n (+ 2) $ flip (writeArray arr) False
loopA' arr n = for' 4 n (+ 2) $ flip (writeArray arr) False

loopB arr n =
  let f i | i <= n     = do writeArray arr i False
                            f (i+2)
          | otherwise  = return ()
  in f 4

loopC arr n = do
  loopA arr n
  loopB arr n

runPrimes loop n = do
    let sr = floor . (sqrt::Double->Double) . fromIntegral $ n+1
    a <- newArray (2,n) True :: (ST s (STUArray s Int Bool))

    loop a n

    forM_ [3,5..sr] $ \i -> do
        si <- readArray a i
        when si $
            forM_ [i*i,i*i+i+i..n] $ \j -> writeArray a j False
    return a

primesA  n = [i | (i,p) <- assocs $ runSTUArray $ runPrimes loopA  n, p]
primesA' n = [i | (i,p) <- assocs $ runSTUArray $ runPrimes loopA' n, p]
primesB  n = [i | (i,p) <- assocs $ runSTUArray $ runPrimes loopB  n, p]
primesC  n = [i | (i,p) <- assocs $ runSTUArray $ runPrimes loopC  n, p]

main = let n = 10000000 in
  defaultMain [ bench "loopA"  $ nf primesA  n
              , bench "loopA'" $ nf primesA' n
              , bench "loopB"  $ nf primesB  n
              , bench "loopC"  $ nf primesC  n ]
```

Comment: I chose to implement the loop manually rather than use forM_ because it was a little faster when I tried it.  I guess `for` versus `for'` depends on a lot of things.

Comment: @yairchu: I'm sorry—I mistyped and have corrected. If I ever suddenly discover that I'm able to use compilers from the future I'll make a point of being clearer about it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps compare and contrast with the Shootout nsieve program? in any case, the only way to know what really is happening is to [look at the core](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html#id679074) (e.g. with [the ghc-core tool](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core)).

```
{-# OPTIONS -O2 -optc-O -fbang-patterns -fglasgow-exts -optc-march=pentium4 #-}
--
-- The Computer Language Shootout
-- http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/
--
-- Contributed by Don Stewart 2005
-- nsieve over an ST monad Bool array
--

import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Base
import System
import Control.Monad
import Data.Bits
import Text.Printf

main = do
    n <- getArgs >>= readIO . head :: IO Int
    mapM_ (\i -> sieve (10000 `shiftL` (n-i))) [0, 1, 2]

sieve n = do
   let r = runST (do a <- newArray (2,n) True :: ST s (STUArray s Int Bool)
                     go a n 2 0)
   printf "Primes up to %8d %8d\n" (n::Int) (r::Int) :: IO ()

go !a !m !n !c
    | n == m    = return c
    | otherwise = do
          e <- unsafeRead a n
          if e then let loop j
                          | j < m     = do
                              x <- unsafeRead a j
                              when x $ unsafeWrite a j False
                              loop (j+n)

                          | otherwise = go a m (n+1) (c+1)
                    in loop (n `shiftL` 1)
               else go a m (n+1) c
```